# Nodejs EINVAL error with UDP bind on Win 7

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp

I am getting a UDP bind error EINVAL only on nodejs 10.5 on windows 7.
Node 6 and 8 dont fail and it works under linux. This is annoying to say the least because I do all basic development under windows. one odf the big Node advantages.

The bind call (in new async form) fails but also the intrinsic bind in the send method fails.
Actually I only want to send data (broadcast) and so i would not normally bind the socket, however, the send method does this automatically. I have verified this by usinf the bind method and this fails as well.

```
Created Dgram socket 255.255.255.255:3001

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' eve
              ^
Error: bind EINVAL
    at errnoException (dgram.js:440:11)
    at dgram.js:207:28
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:
```

From the error stack : Why is the send call using DNS when the address is specified as an an addres and not a string?

Can somebody please verify that send works on windows 7 in 10.5
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can't set the broadcast flag until after the datagram is bound to a port (the port is bound to port 0 if you don't bind it before sending).  The following code snippet shows how to implement the logic.

```
var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

console.log('binding');
client.bind(0);

client.on('listening', function () {

    console.log('setting broadcast flag');
    client.setBroadcast(true);

    console.log('sending');
    client.send(message, 0, message.length, 41234, '255.255.255.255', function (err, bytes) {
        console.log("Sent message: " + err);
        client.close();
    });
});
```